# Calculating the average of random numbers in a nested loop?

Tags: java

```
int num = (int)(Math.random() * 50) + 50;
double total = 0;
for (int row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Grades for student #" + row);
  for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
    num = (int)(Math.random() * 50) + 50;
    System.out.print(num + ", ");
    total += num * 1.0;
  }

  System.out.println();
  double average = total / 10;
  System.out.println("Average for student is " + average);
}
```

I need to find the average grade for each student. Grades are randomly generated. The code prints out the correct average for the first line of data but the other 4 are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset `total` to 0 in the outer loop for each run.

```
for (int row=1; row<=5; row++) {
        double total = 0;  // <-- Move this inside the loop.
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Grades for student #" + row);
        for (int col = 0; col<10; col++) {
            double num = (int)(Math.random()*50)+50;
            System.out.print(num+ ", ");
            total += num; // no need to multiply by 1.0
        }
         
         System.out.println();
         double average = total/10;
         System.out.println("Average for student is " + average);         
}
```

Comment: Note that this answer will print the values as a double.  If that is not what  you want, all  you need to do is change `double num` to `int num`.  You can always add an  int to a double as in `total += num`.